# Upload image and text to server Lua/Corona SDK

Tags: sdk, lua, coronasdk

I have a question related to uploading text and image to server with Corona Sdk. Would it be possible to accpmplish this in Corona and if yes, would it be possible to take a picture with the  phone or select picture from album and then upload it to a server, with a text descreption? Please guide mé in the right direction :)

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Corona SDK provides you the means to make HTTP POST requests (see [Corona Docs: API > Libraries > network > request](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/network/request.html)) which allows you to use POST requests for uploading text and images to a web server.

Although related to uploading images to Twitter, Vellum Interactive's blog post [Post Images to Twitter With Corona SDK](http://velluminteractive.com/upload-images-to-twitter-from-corona-sdk/) might prove really handy. Even if you take all the bits concerning the Twitter API out, it seems to have plenty of knowledge and code that you can apply to your case too.

For your latter question: with [Corona SDK API reference: media.show()](http://developer.coronalabs.com/reference/index/mediashow) you can access the platform-specific implementation photo library or camera which should be what you're looking for. There are no off-the-shelf implementations of this though so you may need to prepare for a good bit of hacking. But if you're ready for it, the Corona SDK reference is quite good.